# How to mount ext partitions on Windows 8

Tags: linux, windows-8, mount, ext

I have Linux installed on my PC along with Linux (Ubuntu). How can I access files from Windows 8 which are present on the Linux's partition?

Comment: Ext2fsd doesn't not support Windows 8 by default. you have to manually patch it to run in Windows 8.

Comment: Your answer does not address that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install a third-party driver which can add support for ext partitions. Doing this on Windows XP or Vista is straightforward, but on Windows 7, 8 and 8.1, the available drivers won't work that easily.

Follow these steps:

```
> Download Ext2Fsd from here: http://www.ext2fsd.com
> Right click and choose Properties and set 'compatibility mode' to 
  'Vista Service Pack 2'. Also enable 'Run as Administrator'.
> Install Ext2Fsd.
> By default, Ext2Fsd only supports ext2 and ext3. To make it support ext4
  file-system, download the patch from here: http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/.
> Unzip the downloaded patch and copy the `ext2fsd.sys` file from the folder
  corresponding to your OS and OS architecture into `Windows/System32/Drivers`
  folder. Replace the existing file.
> Restart your system.
```

Source: http://driesve.tumblr.com/post/1560794187/how-to-mount-an-ext4-drive-in-windows-7

Comment: We expect more then a link to an external website with a solution. Please provide the directions on this website and reference the link you have provided as a source.  Once you do that I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @Ramhound; thanks for the feedback. It helps a newbie become more familiar with the stackexchange site's model.

Comment: ext2fsd v0.52 (released today, 05/11/14) includes official Windows 8 support